# i want to make batch file which move files to another director and rename files if exixt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make batch file which move files from one directory to another and rename files if exit here is my code but not running, programming is auto closing after opening.

```
set fromfiles="D:\TPS\UBPS\BillFiles\FESCO*.*"  
for %%a in (%fromfiles\*.*) do move "%%a" "D:\Billing Data\FESCO"\%%~na_%dtst%%%~xa%"
```

Comment: if this program is wrong kindly write program of move files and rename files if exit.

Comment: I guess you run this batch by double clicking in Explorer. Open it from a shell and you will see what happens. At least from what you post here I would say you are missing the second `%` after `%fromfiles`. Writing `*.` twice will not help too. Perhaps it is best if you only `echo %%a` before calling `move` while you are still hunting bugs. Plus I am rather sure you are not running this on _DOS_ so please remove that tag (have a look at its description). While you are removing tags: think about `c#` and `python` too, you won't make any new friends by misusing tags ;-)

Comment: actually this is .bat file created in notepad in windows 7,

Comment: how can i make this programme in notepad and save as in .bat file

Comment: ahm - in Notepad klick "File" - "save as". Change filetype from ".txt" to "All files" (this prevents Notepad to automatically add a `.txt` to the filename). As filename enter `whatever-I-want-to-name-the-file.bat`. Be sure to select "ANSI" as coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "fromfiles=D:\TPS\UBPS\BillFiles\FESCO*.*"  
for %%a in ("%fromfiles%") do move "%%a" "D:\Billing Data\FESCO"\%%~na_%dtst%%%~xa"
pause
```

The change to the first line (moving the quote) ensures that there are no stray spaces appended to the string assigned.

The second line - need to quote the variable (since it will no longer be quoted and contains spaces) and need the matching `%` at the end of the variablename.

The `pause` command will stop the window auto-closing.

save the file as `whateveryoulike.bat" and in notepad, set "Save as type" to "All files". An preferably, use a better editor. Notepad tries to work like a word-processor and often mangles code.

Comment: but not working my file is not moving to another directory,i just copy and paste your command.

Comment: You should change `move "%%a" ...` to `move "%%~a" ...` to avoid double-doublequotes...

Comment: kindly please make programme of this movefiles to another directory and rename if file exist

Comment: set "fromfiles=D:\TPS\UBPS\BillFiles\FESCO*.*"  
for %%a in ("%fromfiles%") do move "%%~a" "D:\Billing Data\FESCO"\%%~na_%dtst%%%~xa"
pause


this is not working to after inserting ~ in %%a

Comment: Like I already suggested: add `echo` in front of `move` and show us the output